How to speed up users query in WordPress?
I have created a plugin where employers are able to search freelancers and hire them. Freelancer can select dates from a calendar to mark those dates as available to work.

Employers search between dates (from and to) to see the available freelancers then they can shortlist or send job brief to them.
The problem is when employer select two dates which has many days gap, the query just goes on time out.
I have tried adding availability dates into user_meta as an array then queried as following but its obvious that gap of many days will have time out problem as I was using LIKE.
$date_query = array();

if ( ! empty( $from ) && ! empty( $to ) ) {

  $start = new DateTime( $from );
  $end = new DateTime( $to );
  $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); // Include the end date in the period
  $interval = new DateInterval( 'P1D' ); // 1 Day interval
  $date_range = new DatePeriod( $start, $interval ,$end );
  $date_query = [ 'relation' => 'AND' ];

  foreach( $date_range as $date ) {

    $date_query[] = array(
      'key' => 'fmaa_available_dates',
      'value' => $date->format( 'Y-m-d' ),
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );

  }

}

I also tried to add them into separate user meta using add_user_meta() but that also caused the same problem as the query goes too long for having a lot of days.
if ( ! empty( $from ) && ! empty( $to ) ) {

  $start = new DateTime( $from );
  $end = new DateTime( $to );
  $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); // Include the end date in the period
  $interval = new DateInterval( 'P1D' ); // 1 Day interval
  $date_range = new DatePeriod( $start, $interval ,$end );
  $date_query = [ 'relation' => 'AND' ];

  foreach ( $date_range as $date ) {

    $date_query[] = array(
      'key' => 'fmaa_availability_dates',
      'value' => $date->format( 'Y-m-d' ),
      'compare' => 'IN'
    );

  }

}


instead of looping $date_range like that try adding empty $dates = []; and then foreach( $date_range as $date ) { $dates[] = $date->format( 'Y-m-d' ); } after that pass $dates in your single $date_query which will improve alot and IN is better than LIKE . Best option in more complex queries is using sql

I ended up checking only for start and end date of freelancer availability instead of checking each and every date. There are flaws to this like if a freelancer is not available on a day or two in between he will still show on results, but checking for each and every day made the query lengthy and slow as some searches includes 1-2 months.
if ( ! empty( $from ) && ! empty( $to ) ) {

  $start = new DateTime( $from );
  $end = new DateTime( $to );
  $date_query = [ 'relation' => 'AND' ];

  $date_query[] = array(
    'key' => 'fmaa_available_dates',
    'value' => $start->format( 'Y-m-d' ),
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
  );

  $date_query[] = array(
    'key' => 'fmaa_available_dates',
    'value' => $end->format( 'Y-m-d' ),
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
  );

}


you can add to count how many working days there are between start and end and compare to how many free days for the consultant and filter if the two differs
